# Комбинаторика на Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Необходимо создать список всевозможных номеров ОГРН для города Санкт-Петербург (78). Всего в ОГРН 13 цифр, логика которых достаточно проста. Пока что подбираю только 12 из 13 цифр, так как ошибка выходит именно в этом интервале. В итоге вышел следующий код. Но, видимо я чего-то не учел, в следствии чего выходит битый список: 
[image: Пример. Затем возвращает 12 - форматный результат только на 200000 строке.]

```
file = File.new('./file.txt', 'w')
one = 1
            (5..15).to_a.each do |two_three|
            if two_three.to_s.length == 1
                two_three = "0#{two_three}"
            end

                        four_five = 78

        arr1 = (2..27).to_a
        arr2 = [0,1,5,6,13,14]
        arr3 = arr1-arr2
        arr3.each do |six_seven|
            if six_seven.to_s.length == 1
                six_seven = "0#{six_seven}"
            else six_seven = "#{six_seven}"
            end
                Array.new(100000) do 

                    |index| index + 1

                    if index.to_s.length == 1
                        eight_twelve = "0000#{index}"
                    elsif index.to_s.length == 2
                        eight_twelve = "000#{index}"
                    elsif index.to_s.length == 3
                        eight_twelve = "00#{index}"
                    elsif index.to_s.length == 4
                        eight_twelve = "0#{index}"
                    end

        file.puts "#{one}#{two_three}#{four_five}#{six_seven}#{eight_twelve}"
                end
        end
end
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: а вам не кажется что они идут тупо по порядку. может просто прогнать цикл и получить индекс

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: я тту прочитал 2-й, 3-й знаки – две последние цифры года внесения записи в ЕГРЮЛ; какой минимальный год??  91??

Comment: @Санитариум, не совсем по порядку. Есть правила формирования ОГРН номера. К примеру, вторая и третья цифра - это всегда год регистрации, а 6-7 налоговая инспекция, к которой приписано лицо. После получения списка я хочу проверить битые ссылки с одного сайта, используя эти огрн-ы, так что стараюсь по возможности сократить количество вариантов.

Comment: @Санитариум, я сократил выборку с 2005 до 2015

Comment: А Вы можете переформатировать вопрос, чтобы хотя бы код можно было внятно читать?

Answer (score 0):

есть такой вариант

```
var years = ['05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15']
var gos_sign = ['1','5','2','6','7','8','9']

const result = [];
for (let z = 0; z < gos_sign.length; z++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j != 999999; j++) {

      var a = gen_midl(j);
      var K  = a[5];
      var last = +K % 11;
      result.push(`${gos_sign[z]}${years[i]}78${a}${last.toString()[0]}`);
    }
  }
}


function gen_midl(num) {
  var msx_l = 6;
  var c_l = num.toString().length;
  var Y = msx_l - c_l;
  var r = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < Y; i++) {
    r += '0';
  }
  return r + num.toString();
}
console.log(result.length);
```

у меня консоль в хроме падает много очень получается
 около 100кк